# How can I make Windows Task Scheduler fire an event when there's a change of power source detected?

Tags: windows, windows-10, power-management, scheduled-tasks, event-log

I've written a script that successfully sends me a Telegram message describing the battery state of my PC.

I'd like Task Scheduler to run the script when the power source changes, so that when the power at home dies, I know that my fridge is in danger of defrosting etc. etc.

What I've done to achieve this:

- Opened Event Viewer
- Found the event under Windows Logs -> System, Source is "Kernel-Power"
- Clicked "Attach Task To This Event"
- Set up the task and successfulyl run it manually from Task Scheduler

My problem is that the task **does not** fire when the computer switches to battery.  It **does** fire when the computer switches back to mains, which doesn't help me!

I've made sure to turn off the default tickbox of "Start the task if the computer is on AC power", so I'd expect the task to fire in all circumstances.

I've also set it to "Run whether the user is logged on or not", though I'm nearly always logged on.

The events look pretty similar from the event log, but this one fires:

```
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
<System>
<Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Power" Guid="{331c3b3a-2005-44c2-ac5e-77220c37d6b4}" /> 
<EventID>105</EventID> 
<Version>1</Version> 
<Level>4</Level> 
<Task>100</Task> 
<Opcode>0</Opcode> 
<Keywords>0x8000000000000404</Keywords> 
<TimeCreated SystemTime="2019-03-05T17:21:55.021810500Z" /> 
<EventRecordID>75824</EventRecordID> 
<Correlation /> 
<Execution ProcessID="4" ThreadID="336" /> 
<Channel>System</Channel> 
<Computer>Matthew-PC</Computer> 
<Security UserID="S-1-5-18" /> 
</System>
<EventData>
<Data Name="AcOnline">true</Data> 
<Data Name="RemainingCapacity">68</Data> 
<Data Name="FullChargeCapacity">100</Data> 
</EventData>
</Event>
```

and this one doesn't:

```
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
<System>
<Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Power" Guid="{331c3b3a-2005-44c2-ac5e-77220c37d6b4}" /> 
<EventID>105</EventID> 
<Version>1</Version> 
<Level>4</Level> 
<Task>100</Task> 
<Opcode>0</Opcode> 
<Keywords>0x8000000000000404</Keywords> 
<TimeCreated SystemTime="2019-03-05T17:21:44.661890000Z" /> 
<EventRecordID>75823</EventRecordID> 
<Correlation /> 
<Execution ProcessID="4" ThreadID="336" /> 
<Channel>System</Channel> 
<Computer>Matthew-PC</Computer> 
<Security UserID="S-1-5-18" /> 
</System>
<EventData>
<Data Name="AcOnline">false</Data> 
<Data Name="RemainingCapacity">68</Data> 
<Data Name="FullChargeCapacity">100</Data> 
</EventData>
</Event>
```

So does anyone know why the task doesn't fire?  It *feels* like a power saving measure somewhere else in Windows but I  can't work it out (something hidden in the power scheme??)

Answer (score 1):

Windows task scheduler tasks trigger only if the task is:

- Not set to Start the task only if the computer is idle... (task doesn't use IdleSettings)
- Not set to run during automatic maintenance (task doesn't use MaintenanceSettings)
- Is set to Run only when user is logged on (task LogonType is TASK_LOGON_INTERACTIVE_TOKEN or TASK_LOGON_GROUP)

All other triggers are delayed until the system exits battery saver mode.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/design/component-guidelines/battery-saver

Answer (score 0):

when set the Task ,in no.4 option is prerequisite(my languege isn't english ,i don't know in your system is call this ,from left to right ,fourth option) ,second option "power" is default open ,cancel it!
But it will be a question that you on/off the ac all trige.

Answer (score 0):

In task scheduler, within the properties of the task, under the Conditions tab, uncheck "start this task only if computer is on AC power".